# Avoid image conversion by pre-converting to .webp nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, digital-ocean, webp

I am currently running a small Nextjs app on the lowest tier in DigitalOcean. When loading my web app, the images take almost 500ms each to render when they are only 1-2 KB. Could a possible reason for the delay be the time it takes to convert the original `.png` file to `.webp`? If so, how can I modify next/image to also take both a pre-converted `.webp` and a `.png` image and correctly choose between the two in case `.webp` is not supported on a browser?

Comment: Are you sure the issue is with `next/image`? Have you tried loading the images with the `<img>` element for comparison?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
//elsewhere in the file    const imgSrc = pathToImage, const name = imageName
  <picture>
      <source
        type="image/webp"
        srcSet={`/images/${name}.webp`}
      />

      <source type={`image/${type}`} srcSet={imgSrc} />
      <img
        src={imgSrc}
        alt={props.alt ?? ""}
        width={props.width}
        height={props.height}
        className={props.className}
      />
    </picture>
```